# C# move path includes invalid characters

Tags: c#, path, rename, move

I've been trying to do a renamer program in c# for 2 different paths and I keep getting error "Path includes invalid characters" I have no clue how to fix it, I've tried adding @ and deleting \ and keeping only one . But still didn't figure out how to fix it. Would love any help.

This is what gives me an error:

```
if (French.Checked)
{
    directoryfile = @"C:\Users\" + curruser + @"\Appdata\Local\fo4renamer\directory.txt";
    label1.Text = directoryfile;
    readpath = File.ReadAllText(directoryfile);
    string shouldwork = readpath + "data";
    string french = shouldwork + "\\french";
    string german = shouldwork + "\\german";
    string tmp = shouldwork + "tmp.txt";
    label1.Text = french;
    string path2 = @"C:\Users\duchacekda\Desktop\e\Renamer\Renamer\bin\Debug\tmp.txt";
    string filename = @"C:\Users\duchacekda\Desktop\e\Renamer\Renamer\bin\Debug\french.txt";
    File.Move(french, german);
}
```

Here is the whole code:
https://pastebin.com/0i7fzh24

Edit: this is the string for curruser
`string curruser = System.Environment.UserName;`

The exception was given by this line

```
 File.Move(french, german);
```

Comment: And the value of `curruser` is...?

Comment: What does the debugger say about the line the error occurs in? And @InBetween beat me to it for the `curruser` value ;)

Comment: What is the content of the file `directory.txt` as that directly impacts what the File.Move command will execute. Also, which line is causing the exception?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine()` your file names or use debugger and watch the variable values in runtime.

Comment: Tell us exactly what you are trying to do within your code block above.

Comment: @InBetween added the curruser to the top.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel I am not able to test the code up until next week but as far as the label gave me the output it was "C:\users\myusername\desktop\folder\data\french", also added the curruser to the top

Comment: @JayV The File.Move(french, german); is line is causing the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[File.ReadAllText Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) : Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file, and then closes the file.

So in your scenario :

```
string french = (Content of directory.txt) + "data" + "\\french";
```

**It depends on content of directory.txt**

a) If content = directory path(c:\foo) there is no problem

b) if content = "dummy text *** dummy text" then it will throw exception

Please check content of file

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to add that the file has normal path (ie. C:\folder), so its not caused by that

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake, I used WriteLine instead of Write so it added enter on the end of the line which made the path incorrect, thanks for the help